# SVG clipPath - clipped area offset and size problem

Tags: svg, clip, clip-path

Please see the yellow rectangle, this is exactly the same as the rectangle clipping the image.
However image is clipped smaller and moved right.

The image is just one element, but imagine few more elements which all need to be clipped to a shape of a yellow rectangle.

I know I can fix this by wrapping the `<image>` element (and any more elements) inside a `<g>` element and applying the clipPath to this `<g>` element.

Is it possible to fix this issue by modifying just the clipPath part, without touching the rest of the svg structure?

```
<defs>
    <clipPath id="clipPath">
        <path d="M150-750 L150,750 L-150,750 L-150,-750Z" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,152.5,770.5)"></path>
    </clipPath>
</defs>

<path fill="#ffff00" d="M150-750 L150,750 L-150,750 L-150,-750Z" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,152.5,770.5)"></path>

<image x="-1632" y="-1224" width="3264" height="2448" preserveAspectRatio="none"
       xlink:href="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/07/25/01/22/cat-2536662_960_720.jpg"
       transform="matrix(0.3529,0,0,0.3529,246.2554,998.5607)"
       style="clip-path: url(#clipPath);"></image>
```

Please see the [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/3fL8soej/).

Answer (score 0):

Everything happens because you transform the path and the image with a different value. I've removed the transforms and changed the viewBox value so that the clipping path falls inside the svg canvas.

Also I've removed the height of the svg element because I wanted to keep the same aspect ratio as the viewBox.

Please take a look. Let me know if this is what you need.

```html
<svg width="305" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;"
     viewBox="-200 -800 750 3964" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="clipPath">
            <path id="test" d="M150-750 L150,750 L-150,750 L-150,-750Z" ></path>
        </clipPath>
    </defs>

    <use xlink:href="#test" fill="#ffff00" ></use>

    <image x="-1632" y="-1224" width="3264" height="2448" preserveAspectRatio="none"
           xlink:href="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/07/25/01/22/cat-2536662_960_720.jpg"
           
           style="clip-path: url(#clipPath);"></image>
</svg>
```

Comment: In this case why do you use a different transformation for the clipping path?

Comment: "What is the purpose of the <use> tag in your example": you are using the same path twice. Instead of repeating myself I'm reusing the path with `<use>`

Comment: "Because these are manipulated by the user :) So e.g. 4 different elements with different transforms need to be clipped by one clippath" In this case your code works as intended

Comment: It doesn't work as the clipped area is incorrect. It should be clipped to a yellow rectangle which is the same as the clippath.

Comment: 'In this case your code works as intended' No it doesn't